# Unity analytics working in editor but not in build

Tags: unity-game-engine, analytics

I have a weird issue. My Unity analytics work fine in editor but in build for ios or android I get an error on initialization.

```
{severity:critical, message:DependencyTreeComponentHashException: Exception of type 'Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeComponentHashException' was thrown. Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.GetPackageTypeHashFor (System.Int32 componentTypeHash) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.SortTreeThrough (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] dependencyTypeHashes) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.SortTreeThrough (System.Int32 packageTypeHash) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.SortRegisteredPackagesIntoTarget () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeServicesAsync () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeServicesAsync () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeAsync (Unity.Services.Core.InitializationOptions options) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeAsync (Unity.Services.Core.InitializationOptions options) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.UnityServices.InitializeAsync (Unity.Services.Core.InitializationOptions options) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.UnityServices.InitializeAsync (Unity.Services.Core.InitializationOptions options) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Analytics.AnalyticsEventHandler.Start () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Analytics.AnalyticsEventHandler.Start () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Rethrow as DependencyTreePackageHashException: Component with hash[-1271305056] threw exception when sorting package[-767424672][Ua2CoreInitializeCallback] Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.SortTreeThrough (System.Int32 packageTypeHash) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.DependencyTreeInitializeOrderSorter.SortRegisteredPackagesIntoTarget () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeServicesAsync () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeServicesAsync () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeAsync (Unity.Services.Core.InitializationOptions options) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0) Unity.Services.Core.Internal.UnityServicesInternal.InitializeAsync
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering this was fixed by downgrading RemoteConfig from 3.2.2 to 2.1.2.
Apparently this issue is because of the Authentication package added by remote config.